# Finding Best approximation in space with standard inner product

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products, approximation

I'm new to functional analysis. I do not know how to solve the below problem. I know that for g to be the best approximation of f, it has to satisfy the condition that (f−g)⊥G. But I could not apply it in this case.

Consider C[-1,1] (space of continuous functions in [-1,1]) and G:={g $\epsilon$ C[-1,1] | g(x)=g(-x) for all x}. Assume that C[-1,1] is equipped with the standard L^2[-1,1] inner product. Find the best approximation of $x^{{3}}$ + $x^{{2}}$ + $e^{{-x}}$ in G.

Could you please help me with how to approach the solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Note that x^2 is even and x^3 is odd.  e^{-x} can be expressed as the sum of an even function and an odd function.  You might guess that the sum of the even parts is the best approximation.  Then apply the theorem you referenced.

Comment: @NicNic8 Thanks a lot for the hint. How to decide on the number of terms in the approximation function? Is it a1+ a2x^2 and finding a1 and a2 from the theorem, or is it taking till x^4 or x^6?

Comment: It's taking all the way to infinity.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Then how can I find the solution to the best approximation, or How can I find coefficients of the infinite terms? Or is there any other way of finding the best approximation? Could you please tell me more about the approach here? I highly appreciate your help!

Comment: @krishnakaushik There is a much easier way.

Comment: You find the solution by taking it all the way to infinity; you need $a_1$ and $a_2$ and $a_3$ and $a_4$ and so on. But (as indicated in the answers that have been posted since my comment) every function $f$ can be written, in a unique way, as $f=g+h$, where $g$ is even and $h$ is odd; it follows that $f(-x)=g(x)-h(x)$, so you have two linear equations in the two unknowns $g$ and $h$. Solve them, and you get the $g$ that you need.

Comment: exp(-x) = 0.5( exp(-x) + exp(x) ) + 0.5 ( exp(-x) - exp( x ) ).  The first term is even; the second is odd.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the subspace $$H=\{f\,:f(x)=-f(x)\}$$ is orthogonal to $G.$
We have $$\displaylines{F(x):=x^3+x^2+e^{-x}=\left [x^3+{1\over 2}(e^{-x}+e^{x})\right ]+\left [x^2+{1\over 2}(e^{-x}+e^x)\right ]\\=[x^3+\sinh x]+[x^2+\cosh x]}$$
The first term $F_1(x),$ belongs to $H,$ while the second $F_2(x)$ to $G.$
Consider $g\in G.$ Then  by Pythagoras theorem we get
$$\|F-g\|^2=\|F_1+(F_2-g)\|^2=\|F_1\|^2+\|F_2-g\|^2\ge \|F_1\|^2 $$
The best approximation is obtained when $g(x)=F_2(x)=x^2+\cosh x.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $(Ff)(x) = f(-x)$. Note that $g \in G$ **iff** $Fg =g$.

Note that we can write $f$ in its odd & even parts with
$f = {f-Ff \over 2} + {f+Ff \over 2} $.

Then, grinding through the computations we get
\begin{eqnarray}
\|f-h\|^2 &=& \| {f+Ff \over 2} + {f-Ff \over 2} -g \|^2 \\
&=& \| {f+Ff \over 2} -g + {f-Ff \over 2} \|^2 \\
&=& \| {f+Ff \over 2} -g \|^2 + \| {f-Ff \over 2} \|^2 + 2 \langle {f+Ff \over 2} -g , {f-Ff \over 2} \rangle \\
&=& \| {f+Ff \over 2} -g \|^2 + \| {f-Ff \over 2} \|^2 
\end{eqnarray}
Note that ${f+Ff \over 2} \in G$, hence we have
$\min_{g \in G} \|f-g\| = \| {f-Ff \over 2} \|$ and the minimising $g$ is given by $g={f+Ff \over 2} $.

Hence the best approximation is $x \mapsto x^2 + \cosh x$.

**Note**:

A much shorter version would be use the theorem you mentioned and to note that
$\langle {f-Ff \over 2} , g\rangle = 0$ for all $g \in G$ and that
${f-Ff \over 2} = f - {f+Ff \over 2}$, from which it follows that $g= {f+Ff \over 2}$ is the solution.